# How to pass props to component changing just one value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to renderer component different time in a page in this way:

```
render() {

  const propsUpload = {
     customRequest: this.uploadMedia,
     listType: 'picture',
     defaultFileList: [],
     className: 'upload-list-inline',
  }

  return (
     <Upload  {...propsUpload}> </Upload>
     <Upload  {...propsUpload}> </Upload>
     <Upload  {...propsUpload}> </Upload>
  )
}
```

For each Upload component, I need to add a key on propsUpload.
I tried diffente solution, but no one worked.
What I need is something like that:

```
<Upload  {...propsUpload, key:'1'}> </Upload>
<Upload  {...propsUpload, key:'2'}> </Upload>
<Upload  {...propsUpload, key:'3'}> </Upload>
```

How can I reach this gol without define 3 constants for propsUpload?
In other word I want avoid this:

```
 const propsUpload1 = {
    customRequest: this.uploadMedia,
    listType: 'picture',
    defaultFileList: [],
    className: 'upload-list-inline',
    key : '1'
 }
 const propsUpload2 = {
    customRequest: this.uploadMedia,
    listType: 'picture',
    defaultFileList: [],
    className: 'upload-list-inline',
    key : '2'
 }
 const propsUpload3 = {
    customRequest: this.uploadMedia,
    listType: 'picture',
    defaultFileList: [],
    className: 'upload-list-inline',
    key : '3'
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `<Upload key="1" {...propsUpload} />`

Comment: Didn't work because I am using an api that returns me "propsUpload" object so I need to have the key property value in this object

Comment: I think your code for spreading the object and merging the key in would be a good solution but why doesn't that work?  The only thing I can think of is that it may need to look like: `{...propsUpload,{key:'3'}}` in order to merge the two objects together

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
render() {
    const propsUpload = {
      customRequest: this.uploadMedia,
      listType: 'picture',
      defaultFileList: [],
      className: 'upload-list-inline',
    }

    return [1, 2, 3].map((item) => { return <Upload  {...propsUpload} key={item}> </Upload > })
  }
```